# Member type in PowerShell (ScriptProperty, Property, and NoteProperty)

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

What are the member types in PowerShell, like ScriptProperty, Property, Method, NoteProperty, Alias, and EventProperty?

For example, `CPU` is ScriptProperty. How can we classify it as ScriptProperty?

I would like brief information about all of them.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There used to be a great introduction on MSDN to the *PowerShell Extended Type System* (unfortunately lost with the changes since PSH v1).

Essentially PowerShell allows an underlying .NET object to be wrapped with additional members via the [PSObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/system.management.automation.psobject%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) type. This can be done in a number of ways:

- Using `Add-Member` (giving maximum control)
- Specifying additional properties by passing a hash rather than a name to `Select-Object`'s property parameter
- Using `New-Object` to create a `PSObject` and passing
- In .NET code (C#, VB, …) using the underlying `PSObject` properties and [`PSMemberInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/system.management.automation.psmemberinfo%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) sub-types.

The different types of "extended" member are represented by those `PSMemberInfo` sub-types, including:

- NoteProperty: a .NET object or value.
- AliasProperty: an alias for another property (eg. a collection could have both a Count and a Length property with one being another name for the other).
- ScriptProperty: a property with get and set methods written in PowerShell.
- CodeProperty: a property with get and set methods written in C#, VB, ….

and so forth.

Answer (score 9):

See the  [PSMemberTypes Enumeration page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psmembertypes%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)